# Reusing Private Methods in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Most of the s[earched questions](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=reuse%20private%20methods%20rails&oq=reuse%20private%20methods%20rails&gs_l=serp.3..0i71k1l8.0.0.0.13896.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.serp..0.0.0.pW6Mew0KtvI) so far relates to "what's the difference". I need to know how to reuse each across different controllers.

Below is just an example.

**ApplicationController:**

```
private
 def redirect
  redirect_to welcome_path
 end
```

**Any Controller:**

```
class AnyController < ApplicationController
 before_action :redirect, only: :about

 def about
 end
end
```

I now have many controllers that uses the same private methods and wanted to a central place to store it. You know, keeping it DRY sort of thing. Where to place these private methods to reuse across any controller that inherits from ApplicationController? If a question like this has already been answered, please point me there. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a contradiction to use `private` as `public`? Do you understand the difference between `private` and `public` methods?

Comment: @Зелёный Yes I do. I've also figured it out from an old book I found. I've place the private methods in a module in `app/controllers/concerns/private_rules.rb` then include the module in `applicationcontroller`. Happy days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where to place these private methods to reuse across any controller
>   that inherits from ApplicationController?

If you want the classes that inherit from `ApplicationController` to have the method, you just need to put it in `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 private

 def redirect_to welcome_path
 end
end

class AnyController < ApplicationController
  # gets the redirect_to welcome_path method
end
```

This is why `ApplicationController` exists.

Re: modules, it doesn't need to be in a module unless you eventually want to mix it into another class besides `ApplicationController`.